# How maven war dependency actually works?

Tags: java, maven, war

Assume I have following dependency

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>Group</groupId>
     <artifactId>AID</artifactId>
     <version>${project.version}</version>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
     <type>war</type>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
      <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
  </dependency>
```

Seems this code dosn't work since I have excluded library in crated war file. So is there any specification how war dependency works?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean when you say `this code doesn't work`?

Answer (score 0):

When you depend on WAR you're using "overlay" feature:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-overlay.html

Are you trying to achieve "overlay" functionality or trying to depend on JARs from within WAR?